# How to select an element produced by particular instance of a JSP 2.0 tagfile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

Short version: How can I (using a JQuery or other selector) select an HTML element created by *this instance* of a JSP 2.0 tagfile, which may be used multiple times per page?

Long version:

I have a JSP 2.0 tagfile, like so:

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty" import="org.myapp.model.Question" %> 
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ attribute name="question" required="true" type="org.myapp.model.Question" %>

<div class='singleChoice'>
   <c:forEach items="${question.questionOptions}" var="option">
       <!-- display options... -->
   </c:forEach>
</div>
```

This tag may be used multiple times on a given page. If the size of question.questionOptions is less than 3, I want to add an additional CSS class ('compact') to the 'singleChoice' div produced by this tag. I would like to add logic to the tagfile (JavaScript, additional JSTL, whatever is necessary) to check the length of questionOptions and add the class to the div if necessary.

I know that I can add a script tag to the tagfile, like so:

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(question.questionOptions) < 3}"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div .singleChoice').addClass('compact');
    });
    </script>
</c:if>
```

but since that executes when the entire document is ready, and the tag may appear multiple times in a page, it will apply the 'compact' class to ALL 'singleChoice' divs on the page if any of them meet the criteria for applying it. How can I specify *this* div from within the tagfile, when I don't know the ID (and would like to avoid having to set it)?

Comment: In such cases I always just allow for "id" and/or "className" parameters on the tag. It's the same thing you'd do if you were coding with plain HTML, or any other template system really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to add a class "compact" if `${question.questionOptions}` is less than three? If yes, my proposed solution is to add a condition that set the div with class="singleChoice compact".

```
<c:set var="divClass" value="singleChoice" />
<c:if test="${fn:length(question.questionOptions) < 3}">
   <c:set var="divClass">singleChoice compact</c:set>
</c:if>
<div class='${divClass}'>
    <c:forEach items="${question.questionOptions}" var="option">
        <!-- display options... -->
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

This solution is not tested, though the logic is there if I understood question your correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked beautifully. Exactly the kind of clear, readable solution I was looking for.